# StackExchange-like system but with document/file handling

Tags: document-management, stack-exchange

I'm interested in antenna design, which is modeled using small text files (typically under 3 kb). There's no real place to exchange these now, just some files spread around the web. I'd like to fix that.

The best description of what I'm thinking of would be document management. The initial poster would upload the file and type in a description and tabs. Other users could then comment on the file and make suggestions. Anyone could upload new versions of the file. Some sort of file versioning or history would be needed.

A slightly modified StackExchange would be a perfect solution. One change would make the first post (like the one I'm typing) separate and not part of the comment stream, thus becoming the file description. The normal comment system would be below. Then we need to place the file front and center in the UI, perhaps on the right where we get "Similar Question" now. Tagging and voting like we have here would be fantastic.

And of course, since there's no money in this, it would have to be free or close to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use google drive

Comment: Do you want topic+comments or topic+answers+comments? Could you please detail what would be subject to voting?

Comment: @AidenGrossman: Please make an answer, and detail how comments would be handled.

Comment: Ok let's try this: take the interface you're looking at now. Move the entire discussion thread down to about the 1/2 page mark. Above that put a single text box where you type in the description. On the right, where you have the various status bits, place the file at the top, and any older versions below it.